# Using common methods for Jenkins builds

Tags: java, json, jenkins, groovy

I have multiple Jenkins jobs using pipeline scripts and i use the same method for at least 4 of them

```
def createJiraLinks(def ticketNumbers) {
  ArrayList<String> jiraLinks = new ArrayList<String>();
  for(int i =0; i < ticketNumbers.size(); i++) {
    def jira_json = sh script: """/usr/local/bin/curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" --cert-type PEM --key-type PEM -E /Users/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/certificates/cert.pem --key /Users/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/certificates/cert.pem https://jira.dev.org.co.uk:443/rest/api/2/issue/${ticketNumbers[i]}""", returnStdout: true
    def json = jsonParse(jira_json);
    def summary = json['fields']['summary'].toString();
    jiraLinks.add("[" + ticketNumbers[i] + "](https://jira.dev.org.co.uk/browse/" + ticketNumbers[i] + ")" + " - " + summary);

  }
  return jiraLinks;
}
```

How can i have each pipeline job import this method so that if i ever need to update it i can just do it once, the key part here is having the ability to use `sh script:` as if i run the the curl command using `"String.execute()"` the command fails as i cannot correctly format it

Any advice/tips appreaciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the detailed description at [Extending with Shared Libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).